# Cleanest way to expose __all__ as a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a Python package in which I would like to expose some classes. I will also need to iterate over these classes at some point so I would like to also expose `__all__` as a list of classes, not strings. After trying the numerous methods to do this, I settled on the following in the `__init__.py`:

```
from .a import A
from .b import B
from .c import C
ALL = [A, B, C]
__all__ = [x.__name__ for x in ALL]
```

This works, as I can use `from package import *` to grab all the classes as well as being able to `import package / package.ALL` to be able to iterate over them.

Is there a cleaner (or more correct) way to do this? My main gripe with it is that If I want to add a new class, I'd have to import the classes first that add it to a list. It would be ideal if I could just add the new class in one place.

Comment: Note that x.__name__ returns string not actual class x. Your ALL list is the list of classes you want.

Comment: `__all__` has to contain a list of strings (names that you want exposed) for when I want to do a bulk import using `import *`. I created `ALL` so I could have a list of the actual classes.